# How to add lighting effect in SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklightnode

I am using SpriteKit, does SKLightNode can only work with SKSpriteNode? because there is no shadowCastBitMask property on SKShapeNode, I cannot make SKLightNode work with SKShapeNode. Is there a way can make them work together? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

SKShapeNode does not have lighting properties like SKSpriteNode. If you create a SKShapeNode you can make it disappear into a shadow but you cannot make it cast a shadow or set any other lighting properties.

Comment: is it possible to put an extension on `SKShapeNode()` to get it to conform and have those lighting properties?